# User Access Ctrl for Google Script App with 'Execute as Me' option

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, google-apps-script-api

I have a Google App Script based WebApp for basic CRUD operations with Google sheet as source of data.
This will app be used by multiple users in the team but with restricted access. i.e some users can only Read, some can R & W & others cant have both R/W.

**Requirement 1** :**To avoid sharing the Google Sheet access to all** users, the GAS App is deployed as "**Execute as Me**" and "**Anyone with Google Account**" option by the admin user. This works fine.

**Requirement 2** : **To achieve the user email id based page access control**, I am trying to read App User (with google account) email id via Session.getActiveUser().email to get the email id of the app user , but seems it will be blank as per docs for this method if "Execute as me" option is used.

So is there a way to get the email id of app user (with google account) ? to perform further validation if he has access to the page in the app. For Requirement 2.

**Note** : Requirement 2 could be achieved if "**Execute as user accessing the app**" option is used. But it forces to share the Google Sheet with all the users in order to be able to view the data in the app. Do not want to share the Google Sheet to all users.

I checked few other suggestions like using Token etc mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012888/how-to-properly-configure-gas-web-app-as-another-user-to-execute-gas-api-execu?noredirect=1&lq=1). Looking for anyother quick option if possible as it needs another app creation & a bit of refactoring the apis.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, in this case, how about using 2 Web Apps? At Web Apps "A", it is deployed as `Execute as: User accessing the web app` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account`. At Web Apps "B", it is deployed as `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone with Google account`.

Comment: The flow is as follows. First, the user accesses to Web Apps "A". Web Apps "A" accesses Web Apps "B". Here, the user's email address can be retrieved. Then, Web Apps "B" accesses to your Spreadsheet. By this flow, your Spreadsheet is not required to be shared while the user's email can be retrieved. If I misunderstood your question and this process was not included in your goal. I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thanks for your quick & helpful response. Yes that was one of the option i recently learnt to be possible. But since the app is already built & as it requires 2 applns to maintain , would like to check if there is any other way possible (with just one appln).

Comment: Also pls share if any pointers/ref docs for building Web App A which acts a client/middleware to access Web App B. Is it via API & tokens? Would there be more latency in fetching data as it involves 2 calls.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `But since the app is already built & as it requires 2 applns to maintain , would like to check if there is any other way possible (with just one appln).`, I apologize that my proposal was not useful for your situation. When I found other method, I would like to propose it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , for the option you suggested above " using 2 Web Apps.  First, the user accesses to Web Apps "A". Web Apps "A" accesses Web Apps "B". "
could you share on how to make sure App B is accessible only for App A and should it be an API call ? In that case does it need any token or how does it ensure App B is called  as "Me" with the admin account.